# Android. What is the intent to start Google Play Music App?

Tags: android, google-play

I have used this code to start `Intent` of Google Play Music

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");
startActivity(intent);
```

but it show dialogue with two option Google Play Music and Built in Music Player.
Please help me in start Google Play music app from `Intent`.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by this code.

```
    *Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.music");
    startActivity(intent);*
```

Comment: Does that parse into a text URI that you could share?  I'm looking for similar functionality for an `<a href="...">` tag

Answer (score -1):

is this what your looking for? https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html

Comment: No, This is not what I'm looking for.